# Disappearing components?

Tags: memory, apache-flex

I have a canvas which contains a single myComponentA. A myComponentA contains a MyComponentB. The myComponentB contains a number of myComponentA's giving a tree structure...Ok so far.

The structure is stored as an XML file.

1. When I load a big (60 or so components), the components are not visible... When I change the player quality to low or medium they appear...!?
2. Towards the bottom of the diagram a component is clipped through the middle as though it has been cut off...(The containing canvas continues on empty...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an issue with the flex measuring mechanism. Your `myComponentA` should probably report its `measuredHeight` and `measuredWidth` to the parent container. This will likely be done, in your case, in an override of the `measure` function. e.g,

```
override protected function measure():void {
       measuredWidth = //x position + width of rightmost child
       measuredHeight = //y position + height of bottommost child
       super.measure();
}
```

If you do something like this in both `myComponentA` and `myComponentB`, *and* you inherit from a Container (e.g., canvas) then things should work mostly. If your components inherit from UIComponent, you might have more trouble (i.e., there won't be any scrollbars).

Keep in mind that the `measure` function only sets the `measuredHeight` and `measuredWidth`. Depending on your situation, you may need to overide `updateDisplayList` as well to properly set the actual height/width/positions of the children.